# Taking large integer input in PHP

Tags: php, integer

I want to take integer input in PHP but the integer can be up to 10^12

```
<?php

$input = fopen('php://stdin', "r");
fscanf($input, "%d", $x);
print $x;
?>
```

The above code do not works for input after 10^10.How can we take this integer input?Here is the [link](http://ideone.com/zCCAff)

Comment: You can use a float instead - floats are precise for integers up to `2^51`, which is far, far more than the `10^12` you need. You can then do validation to ensure it's an integer value, etc.

Comment: why can't we use integer as an input just like in C++

Comment: Because `10^12 > 2^31`. But if you have the 64-bit version of PHP then you're all set because `10^12 ≪ 2^63`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes, you cannot have an `int` beyond a certain limit (depending on 32 or 64 bit platform). Your alternative is to use a `float` instead, but this is unsuitable if you require absolute precision. The other alternative is to keep the number as string, and operate on it as string using the [bc math](http://php.net/bc) functions.

```
$number = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
if (!ctype_digit($number)) {
    trigger_error("$number is not a number");
}
echo $number;
echo bcadd($number, 42);
```

Comment: +1 for bc math, but floats do have absolute precision for integers up to the size of the mantissa ;)

Comment: @Niet So, they are precise, unless they aren't...? ;)

Comment: Hehe, fair point. They're precise under certain circumstances, which is generally good enough for me - although I've learned to always use things like `+= 0.125` rather than `+= 0.1` when expecting exact results.